# Passing a JavaScript variable to the view through a HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having an issue passing a JavaScript variable through a form correctly to a controller. I'm not sure how to do this since it's my first time working with JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

My code can be found below:

```
  <script>

   function findDoc(e){
      ...
      var ID = grid._data[rIndex].document_ID;
   }

   ...

   {title: Grab, template: "<form action = '<?php echo $exepath;?> docs/grab' method = 'POST'><input type = 'submit' value = 'ID'></form>", width: 90}

   </script>
```

Comment: Can you post more information? What part are you stuck at? Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: guessing the php echo? view source, what do yo see ?

Comment: I just want a regular button so that when I click it, it sends the ID to the controller so the controller can retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting to concatenate the value of the `ID` JavaScript variable with the string in your code you will have to use JavaScript's [string concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators):

```
{title: Grab, template: "<form action = '<?php echo $exepath;?> docs/grab' method = 'POST'><input type = 'submit' value = '"+ID+"'></form>", width: 90}
```

Also, I don't think you want a space in your action URL between the PHP `echo` and `docs/grab`

Comment: Yeah. It was mistype. I'm trying to send ID to my controller through the form but I'm unsure of how to do it.  I just want a regular button so that when I click it, it sends the ID to the controller so the controller can retrieve it.

Comment: @Requiem you need an `input` element inside of your `<form>` tags with a value, otherwise when you click submit nothing will be sent.

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing though unless there needs to be another input element. Not sure how I'd go about this.

Comment: @requiem The only input element you have is a submit button. You need a `<input type="hidden" value="yourvaluehere" />` etc.

Comment: If I enter an input <input type = "hidden" value = "ID"> however, this still does not appear to work.  Would the ID not be getting evaluated correctly or is there something else wrong?

Comment: @Requiem you have to give it a `name` attribute. Also, don't forget you have to concatenate ID's value with the `+` operator

Comment: Well if I try to do something like this, <input type = 'hidden' name = 'id' value = '"+ID+"'> then I get errors due to the concatenation.

Comment: @Requiem Oh, right.  You will have to populate it with JavaScript. `document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value = ID;` should work. You are correct that the concatenation will not work; I thought you were using JavaScript not HTML.

Comment: And that line would have to go in my javascript function while in the html input tag my name='id' value='ID' correct?

Comment: @Requiem All of that is correct. But don't add `value='ID'` in your HTML, because that line of JavaScript from my comment above will set the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can send javascript variables back to the server using one of two ways :

1)Ajax call to the server
[How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

2)form POST input values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

You can add or modify input fields using javascript and catch them in a $_POST array.